# In python, it shows ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''?

Tags: python, arraylist, integer, valueerror

```
n = int(input("enter nos of items in List: "))
a = []
for i in range(0,n):
    elements = int(input("Enter Elements : "))
    a.append(elements)
    avg = sum(a)/n
print("average of given numbers", round(avg,2))
```

Comment: What did you enter at each of the `input` statements?

Comment: What makes you think that's wrong?

Comment: @PeterWood A ValueError is stating that he is trying to convert a mismatched type. So his problem is likely linked to his inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using validating the user input with a while loop, you can check if the answer contains only number, if it does not, then the loop repeats until the user enters a valid input.

```
n = input("enter nos of items in List: ")
while n.isdigit() != True:
    n = input("Invalid Input!\nEnter nos of items in List: ")

a = []
for i in range(0, int(n)):
    elements = input("Enter Elements : ")
    while elements.isdigit() != True:
        elements = input("Invalid Input!\nEnter Elements : ")
    
    a.append(int(elements))
    
avg = sum(a)/int(n)
print("average of given numbers", round(avg,2))
```

ValueErros can be caused, as the result of the you trying to convert a string containing alphabetic characters into an integer.

Comment: You would need to do the same thing for the second `input()` in the `for` loop